# Can't change screen brightness on Ubuntu 16.04 after installing Intel Graphics for Linux

Tags: drivers, graphics, laptop, intel-graphics, brightness

I've a notebook running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, today I've installed the Intel Graphics for Linux from 01.org, but after rebooting the system, then I can't change screen brightness using `FN + F8` / `FN + F9`

```
*-display UNCLAIMED     
description: VGA compatible controller
product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 2
bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
version: 06
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
configuration: latency=0
resources: memory:f6c00000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64)

filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-59-generic/updates/dkms/i915.ko
license:        GPL and additional rights
description:    Intel Graphics
author:         Intel Corporation
author:         Tungsten Graphics, Inc.
```

At GRUB configuration I've made some modifications:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_pstate=disable video.use_native_backlight=1"
```

But still not working, any idea?

Thanks

Comment: That was a really bad idea to install those drivers. The adapter is unclaimed now, and it is a real problem to remove the driver.

Comment: i have the same problem.